# Columns misplaced when using rows with different number of columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I build a grid with 3 rows, and the next configuration.

In the first one, 3 columns,

In the second one, 2 columns,

In the last one,  columns:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><asp:button /></div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><asp:button /></div>
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><asp:button /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><asp:button /></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"><asp:button /></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"><asp:button /></div>
</div>
```

The problem is the end of each row (I mean, the last column) is not aligned with the others one... I tried to set the specific margin or/and padding in each row. But the issue is still happening because when I change the size of the screen, the mess coming again.

Is there a elegant or efficicent solution for this problem?

Thanks mates.

NOTE: Giving you all additional information, hope you all can understand my problem bettter... Inside of each column I have a different number of elements (like asp:button, asp:label, and so on...). I am using bootstrap 3. If you need any kind of information, please let me know... Cheers.

Comment: can you post all of the page code please?

Comment: You're using `<div>` instead of `</div>` to close off your row...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was a simple HTML error and leaving this question open / answering the question formally provides no benefit to the community.

Comment: @RobertC. I am not sure about it. My code is working correctly and doesnt have an error, it is more that its behaviour is not the expected. Probably, it is a newy error of coding, but it is still an error...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you are trying to make the row with 2 columns have the last column align with the last one in the row with 3? If that's true, then you need to use an offset and have the columns be the same size.

Is this what you are looking for?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-primary">Row 1 Col 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-info">Row 1 Col 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 bg-danger">Row 1 Col 3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-success">Row 2 Col 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 bg-warning">Row 2 Col 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 bg-danger">Row 3 Col 3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also you didn't close your div tags properly on the rows

Comment: Thanks @BlueCaret... Crazy morning.. I check it in the afternoon. Hoping it works, a least I am giving you an upvote just for you efford. Thanks mate.

Comment: Checking the code snippet, looks like you are setting empty columns... I will have the problem again... I want to align the different rows at the END, having different columns size. I mean Row2 Col2 and Row2 col1 should be size both, and Row3 Col3 should be size 12...

Comment: @EliasMP sorry not sure I still understand what you are going for then? Could you maybe draw out what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I would like to achieve 3 rows. All of them, aligned at the beginning and at the end (I mean the 3 rows must to have the same width, including padding and margin, and so on). Therefore, we have 3 rows with different number of columns (First one, 3 columns. Second one, 2 columns. Third one, 1 column) and the finish of the row (right side) must to be aligned in the three rows (and the very same in the opposite side, left side). @BlueCaret. Thanks you for your help :):):)

Comment: I updated the code in my answer, if you rerun the example you will see that I wrapped it in a `.container` class which it should be in anyway and each column is colored to show the alignment easier. Looks like it aligns correctly to me based on what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks again. Yep, that is the idea that I want. I just test it and it is not working. Giving you additional information, hope you can understand my problem bettter... Inside of each column I have a different number of elements (like asp:button, asp:label, and so on...). I am using bootstrap 3. If you need any kind of information, please let me know... Cheers pal.